# tastypie - List related resources keys instead of urls

Tags: tastypie

When I have a related Resource, I would like to list foreign keys, instead of a url to that resource. How is that possible aside from dehydrating it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's possible without dehydrating the field. I usually have utility functions that handle conversion the dehydration of foreign key and many-to-many relationships, something like this:

```
#api_utils.py
def many_to_many_to_ids(bundle, field_name):
    field_ids = getattr(bundle.obj, field_name).values_list('id', flat=True)
    field_ids = map(int, field_ids)
    return field_ids

def foreign_key_to_id(bundle, field_name):
    field = getattr(bundle.obj, field_name)
    field_id = getattr(field, 'id', None)
    return field_id
```

And apply them to the fields like so:

```
#api.py

from functools import partial

class CompanyResource(CommonModelResource):
    categories = fields.ManyToManyField(CompanyCategoryResource, 'categories')

    class Meta(CommonModelResource.Meta):
        queryset = Company.objects.all()

    dehydrate_categories = partial(many_to_many_to_ids, field_name='categories')


class HotDealResource(CommonModelResource):
    company = fields.ForeignKey(CompanyResource, 'company')

    class Meta(CommonModelResource.Meta):
        queryset = HotDeal.objects.all()

    dehydrate_company = partial(foreign_key_to_id, field_name='company')
```